# Integrals definition

Tags: calculus, integration

I had just started a calculus lesson, but the way the instructor explains it, it's kind of dull and hard to understand.

Here's what I already know:

- You use integrals to do something with area under a curve
- Integrals can be expressed as this: $$
  \int_{}
  $$

Can someone briefly summarize, explain and tell me what an integral does and is? And correct me if I'm wrong on the first two statements. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's the area under a curve.

Comment: I always think of it as accumulation of change, where as derivative is rate of change.

Comment: Here is an example closer to home. Look at some plots of Covid cases. They will have a graph of daily cases, and of cumulative cases. If you add all the daily cases up to a certain day, you get the cumulative cases at that day. But you can also consider this sum as the area under the curve of daily cases if each day has 'width' of $1$ (think about that). So the area under the curve is the cumulative cases. Conversely the rate of change of the cumulative cases is the daily cases. So, in a sense, "area under a curve" and "rate of change" can be opposites. What does this suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\displaystyle \int$ is an elongated $S$ and it represents a summation.

It can be used to represent the area under a curve, in which case what you are summing is the area of a series of narrow rectangles.  You could also be summing the application of force over some distance, in which case the integral represents the energy applied.  Or, you could be summing probabilities, in which case the integral would be the probability of seeing an observation that is less than x.

Anyway, areas under the curve, is usually the introductory application.

$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \ dx$ is the area under the curve $f(x)$ over the interval $[a,b]$

[image]

Or the green area above.

But, it is a little bit more than area... it is signed area.  If your curve is below the x-axis, you will have a negative area.  Or if it crosses the x-axis.

[image]

It would be the green area less the red area.

From the Riemann definition of the integral you would partition the region into narrow rectangles, sum the area of the rectangles, and show that when the partition is sufficiently fine, the series converges to some value.  This is the integal.

The really big deal is the Fundamental Theorem of calculus, that says

$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(t) \ dt = F(b) - F(a)$  where $f(t)$ is the derivative of $F(t)$

So $\displaystyle \int f(x) \ dx$ should be thought of as an anti-derivative.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That's more understandable

Comment: I feel that thinking of integrals as anti-derivatives is misleading. Integrals are a lot more general. The fundamental theorem of calculus says an anti-derivative is an integral. But not all integrals are antiderivatives. This is especially true when you start to generalise integrals to higher dimensions, or in the Lebesgue sense. Otherwise, a good answer.

Comment: @epiliam Fair enough.  But, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus is .... fundamental... and in my mind the correct place to start.

Comment: It is a good place to start. But I think that if someone believes that an integral IS an anti-deriavtive then they can get themselves into trouble. I feel that it is better to think of an anti-derivative as a special case of an integral. But that is just my opinion. I also don't like the notation $\int f(x)\,dx$ and much prefer $\int_a^x f(s)\,ds$ as the former has no geometric meaning and is somewhat arbitrarily defined. But - that's just me.